# Installing screen 4.9.0 on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi, gnu-screen

I am working on a script which requires the **terminal emulator program “screen”** to work.

Unfortunately, version 4.8.0 which is the only one I can by default download easily via `sudo apt-get install` contains a bug that makes it unusable for my application.

[image: Avalible downloads as shown by apt list]

**I tried downloading the correct tar file from the [GNU website](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/)**, and following the **install instructions in the INSTALL file**, however half of the scripts they mention there **are not included in the tar file!**

**So my question is:** How do I get **screen 4.9.0** installed on my Raspberry Pi? I need the **arm64** version of the program.

Thank You for your help.

**Edit with additional info:**

Upon running the `./autogen.sh` script, as instructed by INSTALL, I am presented with this error:

```
./autogen.sh: 2: autoreconf: not found
```

Opening up autogen.sh to see what's inside reveals only this single command:

```
#!/bin/sh
autoreconf -i
```

Comment: autogen.sh is most definitely in the source code tar ball. The other files all get generated by that, so there must be a problem running autogen.sh. You need to solve that. We could help – but you'd really need to copy and paste the output of `./autogen.sh` (please don't take screenshots – text is better!) into your question, and use the "code formatting" button (labeled `{}`) on that.

Comment: But, **first**, you're using debian oldstable, is that on purpose? As the name suggests, it's an old release of debian. Just upgrading debian would instantly give you screen 4.9.0

Comment: As well as (or instead of) upgrading to the latest stable, you may want to consider using `tmux` rather than `screen` in your script.  While they both do basically the same job, they have different bugs and different quirks, so `tmux` may work where `screen` won't.   I used screen for decades and resisted all recommendations to switch to tmux because I didn't want to learn something new & different...until I ran into a screen problem that I couldn't work around. I switched to tmux, learnt & adapted to the differences in less than a day, and my only regret is that I didn't switch much sooner.

Comment: Hello, and Thank You for responing. I have added to my question additional information on the errors I am seeing. Looking at this today, I'm starting to suspect maybe autoreconf is just a separate program I need to have?

Comment: `autoreconf` is in the `autoconf` package. you'll probably want to install the `automake` package too.  and if you look at the [control](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/screen/-/blob/master/debian/control) file in the debian source package for `screen`, you'll see that it has `Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 13), dpkg-dev (>= 1.16.1~), libncurses-dev, libpam0g-dev, libutempter-dev, texinfo` so building screen will need all those installed (and everything that they depend upon).

Comment: compiling and backporting stuff can be hard and complicated work, especially if you're not used to it.  like i said, you'll probably be better off trying tmux. or upgrading your rpi's version of debian.  or trying to find a workaround for the problem with your version of screen.

Comment: I have started migrating all my scripts to tmux, as You have suggested. however I have ran into a new issue. I'm starting my session like so: `tmux -S /tmp/tekkit new -d sh launch.sh`. I would like many users to be able to attach to this session, however only the session owner upon running `tmux -S /tmp/tekkit attach` get's connected to the launch.sh terminal, everybody else just get's the owner's linux terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update, It was an error on my part, somewhere else in the script. The above mentioned method works 100%. My appologies.